# What is the expected order of a group generated by $k$ permutations in $S_n$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

Suppose we choose $k$ permutations at random on $n$ elements (let's say with replacement, though it doesn't matter in the limit for large $n$ and fixed $k$), and consider the group $G\le S_n$ generated by these permutations. Let the expected order of $G$ be $q_k(n)$. What does this value look like for large $n$?

It is known that with one random permutation, $\log(q_1(n))\sim c\sqrt{\frac{n}{\log n}}$ for a fixed constant $c\approx 1.118$.

If $k>1$, how does the order of this group compare to that of $S_n$? Is there a $k$ such that the expected order goes to some constant fraction of $n!$ for large $n$?

Some manual results for $k=2$: $q_2(2)= 1.75, q_2(3)=4.19, q_2(4)=13.43,q_2(5)=71.86$. (Curiously, if my computations are correct here, the ratio $q_2(n)/n!$ is not monotonic.)

For fixed $n$, we also have $q_k(2)=2-2^{-k}$ and $q_k(3)=6-3\cdot2^{-k}+12\cdot 3^{-k}-10\cdot 6^{-k}$.

A related question, which puts some bounds on this one, is the probability that $G=S_n$ or that $G=A_n$.

Comment: For any $k \ge 1$, the probability that the group is $A_n$ or $S_n$ approaches $1$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: "... choose k permutations" *uniformly*? "at random ..."

Comment: So you might expect $q_2(n)/n!$ to approach $7/8$ as $n \to \infty$.  I have just been experimenting with $n$ up to $100$ and I am getting results about $0.86$.

Comment: More generally, you'd expect $q_k(n)/n!$ to approach $1 - 1/(2^k \cdot k!)$ - the group is $A_n$ with probability $1/2^k$ (if all the generators are odd) and $S_n$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Performing a search for the probability of generating $S_n$, I found a paper at https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02501 confirming this. Is it known how fast the chance of failing to generate $A_n$ or $S_n$ decays for $k>2$? (When $k=2$ it is asymptotically equal to $1/n$.)

Comment: I'd have to check if it's known, but almost certainly, the error term is dominated by the chance that all elements fall into a big maximal subgroup. In particular, I'd expect the error term to be dominated by the chance that all elements fix the same point. (You can easily compute the probability of this occurring.)

Comment: @MichaelLugo Wouldn't that mean $q_k(n)/n! \sim 1-1/2^{k+1}$? (Also all even, not all odd.)

Comment: @runway44 yes.  I'm not sure why I put a factorial in there; it gives the right answer for k = 2 and I didn't check any further!

Comment: @verret Yes that's right. The dominant term in the chance of not generating $A_n$ or $S_n$ arises from all elements fixing the same point, in which case the group generated is likely to be $A_{n-1}$ or $S_{n-1}$.